# Как запустить приложение на удаленном компьютере под Windows на его экране при подключении через ssh

Tags: windows, cmd, ssh, jenkins

У меня есть exe файл, который запускаясь проводит тесты графики, т.е. открывется окно приложения с мультиплеером, прогоняются тесты и окно закрывается. Если это делать локально, то все проходит нормально, но если запускать подключившись по ssh то приложение появляется в диспетчере задач, но не в интерактивном режиме, т.е. окна не открываются мультиплеера не видно и естественно тесты не проходят. То же самое попробовал сделать с нативным приложением Paint или calc.exe: `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Paint.lnk",  "C:\windows\system32\calc.exe"`
Через командную строку локально, все работает открывается окно и в диспетчере задач появляется служба, а если запускать подключившись по ssh, то только появляется служба.
Команды запуска для exe файла передаются через jenkins, который подключен по ssh к машине с windows. Что нужно сделать что бы можно было запустить приложение в интерактивном режиме на удаленном дисплее под windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока решил реализовать через планировщик задач [SCHTASKS](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/schtasks.html), для калькулятора calc.exe  =):

```
    set HH=%time:~0,2%
    set MM=%time:~3,2%
    set /a allmm=%HH%*60+%MM%+2
    set /a hh=%allmm%/60
    set /a mm=%allmm% "%" 60
    set  hhmm=%hh%:%mm%
    echo hhmm=%hhmm%
    echo time=%time:~-0,5%
    SCHTASKS /Create /ST %hhmm% /SC ONCE /TN calc_test /TR C:\windows\system32\calc.exe /F

/ST %hhmm% - Время запуска задачи. Этот параметр должен использоваться вместе с /SC ONCE
/SC ONCE - Задает расписание и частоту повторения задачи.
/TN calc_test - Название задачи
/TR C:\windows\system32\calc.exe - Путь к исполняемому файлу
/F - Принудительное выполнение, в данном случае (создание задания)
%hhmm% - переменная со значением времени, полученное путем добавления 2 мин ко времени начала выполнения команды `%time%`
```

В итоге получил запланированное задание которое выполнится минимум через 1 минуту максимум через 2 но в интерактивном режиме:

```
    >SCHTASKS /Query /TN "calc_test"

    Folder: \
    TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
    ======================================== ====================== ===============
    calc_test                                11/02/2022 16:57:00    Ready
```

Это время до выполнения задания:

```
>echo %time%
16:55:34.33
```

Задание после выполнения:

```
    >SCHTASKS /Query /TN "calc_test"
    
    Folder: \
    TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
    ======================================== ====================== ===============
    calc_test                                N/A                    Ready
```

При желании можно добавить удаление задания:

```
     >SCHTASKS /Delete /TN "calc_test" /F
```

Если кто знает более элегантное решение вопроса, буду рад услышать и перенять опыт. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с твоей проблемой, чуть модифицировал твое решение.
Я заранее создал несколько задач с однократным выполнением, а после вызывал их таким образом:

```
SCHTASKS /Run /I /TN название
```

1. /Run - запуск
2. /I - запустить сейчас, игнорируя все
3. /TN - название

Отдельное спасибо, за решение с SCHTASKS!)

P.S. Из новых предложений - мнгновенный запуск задания.
Так как планировщик не поддерживает время с секундами при создании задачи через консоль, мое решение будет удобным, дабы не ждать 1-2 минуты после создания задачи.

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы вы изложили в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), что именно нового вы предлагаете (в сравнении с предыдущим ответом).